# Sapui5: How can I preform an action on OPA5 then function?

Tags: sapui5

I have a test journy that clicks a button and expects to a specific answer,
it works like this:

```
When.onTheHomePage.iPressTheSearchButton();
Then.onTheHomePage.iSholdGetResponse(answer);
```

So after I click the button I want to see if I get the correct answer.

The thing is that I want an action that if it didn't find the answer it will click on another button

```
iSholdGetResponse: function (sAnswer) {
    var modelAnswer;
    return this.waitFor({
        viewName: "Home",
        matchers: function (oPage) {
            var sExpectedObj = oPage.getModel("msgData").getData()['msgData'];
            var sExpectedRes = sExpectedObj[sExpectedObj.length-1];
            modelAnswer = sExpectedRes.Text.toLowerCase();

            if(modelAnswer.indexOf(sAnswer.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
                return true;
            }else{
              //NEED TO DO HERE CLICK BUTTON *******
           }
        },
        success: function (data) {
            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Answer Correct! (" +modelAnswer +")");
        },
        errorMessage: "Not expected answer"
    });
}
```

**So how can i trigger a click in matches property?**

Answer (score 1):

you have do it in separate test:

1.Test 1

```
When.onTheHomePage.iPressTheSearchButton();
    Then.onTheHomePage.iSholdGetResponse(answer).and.iSeeTheIncorrectAnswer;
```

2.Test 2

```
When.onTheHomePage.iPressAnAnotherButton();
    Then.onTheHomePage.iSholdGetResponse(answer)...
```